# Erro na hora de pegar os elementos do JSON

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, request, response

Fala galera, blz? Estou com um problema na hora de receber a resposta em JSON do Ajax, não consigo popular todos os estados no select. Apesar de estar dentro de um for ele pega apenas o último elemento, ou seja percorre todos os estados mas só armazena o último... Se alguém souber como proceder com o script, eu agradeço!

> Se fosse no JQuery usaria o .html() para atribuir o valor, mas e em JS puro?
>
> > o select popula apenas com o Tocantins o último elemento
> >
> > > No meu caso o arquivo estados-cidades.json é local
> > >
> > > > LINK estados-cidades.json https://gist.github.com/lucashort7/313bec7d4a8b82472ac19993681d71c2
>
> Obrigado!

[javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[ajax](/questions/tagged/ajax)[json](/questions/tagged/json)

```js
(function(){
    'use strict';

    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

    var $estado = document.querySelector('[data-js="estado"]');

    ajax.open('GET', 'json/estados-cidades.json', true);
    ajax.send(null);

    var options = "<option value=''>selecione o seu estado</option>";
    $estado.innerHTML = options;

    ajax.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){

        if(ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200){
            var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);

            for(var i = 0; i < data.estados.length; i++){
                options = `<option value='${data.estados[i]["sigla"]}'>${data.estados[i]["nome"]}</option>`;

                //$estado.appendChild(options); também nao funciona
                $estado.innerHTML = options;   
            }

        }

    }, false);



})();
```

Answer (score 1):

Você esta sobrescrevendo o conteúdo sempre que chama

```
$estado.innerHTML = options;
```

Coloque o conteúdo em uma variável e depois aplique ao HTML

```
(function(){
    'use strict';

var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();

var $estado = document.querySelector('[data-js="estado"]');

ajax.open('GET', 'json/estados-cidades.json', true);
ajax.send(null);

var options = "<option value=''>selecione o seu estado</option>";
$estado.innerHTML = options;

ajax.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(){

    if(ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200){
        var data = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);

        for(var i = 0; i < data.estados.length; i++){
            options = options + `<option value='${data.estados[i]["sigla"]}'>${data.estados[i]["nome"]}</option>`;                

        }
        $estado.innerHTML = options;   

    }

}, false);

})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Realmente dentro do for eu não estava recebendo a própria variável options 
não notei que faltava receber ela mesmo options += ....

Obrigado Luciano Marqueto, valeu mesmo!

Comment: Oi Igor! Se a resposta do Luciano resolveu o problema podes clicar para marcar como aceite,